# Wrong li offset in html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move down an element with id="email-li" from my ul, but it doesn't move down.
How can I fix it?

I have the next structure:

```css
.contacts-info {
  width: 815px;
  max-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#email-li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts-info">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="assets/images/elaginDoorSmallLogo.svg"></li>
    <li id="email-li">E-mail:<br/>test@gmail.com</li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/pipe.svg"></li>
    <li>Hello1</li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/pipe.svg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: does removing `display: inline-block;` from CSS `li` help?

Comment: @rohitt No, if I'll do that, then the table will not be horizontal

Comment: I'm not sure if you're question is clear. what do you want to move down?

Comment: @rohitt yeah, you are right, I fixed a question, I need to move down element with id="email-li"

Comment: What do you mean under "move down"?

Comment: I just need the inscription: "test@gmail.com" to be below on several pixels for symmetry with other elements of the "ul".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```css
#email-li {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px; /*set how you need*/
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```